# CouchDB install multiple versions side-by-side

Tags: couchdb

I attempt to install multiple versions of CouchDB databases, say 1.1.0 along side with 0.10.0.
By using [build-couchdb](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb) I was able to get the latest version up and running with no problems, now I am trying with installing a second version (0.10.0) but with no success so far. Following with the instructions, I've tried:

```
rake git="git://git.apache.org/couchdb.git tags/0.10.0" install=/full/path/to/couchdb/dir
```

It does a bunch of installs but fails at the end with "rake aborted!".
Have anyone successfully done this ?

Answer (score 2):

Build CouchDB can be slightly brittle. In production, what I've seen is a lot of complete wipes and complete rebuilds. Since people tend to build only once, the build time is not a huge pain-point.

Next, try to use the Erlang shortcut for [installing side-by-side CouchDB](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb) builds. (Search for `couchdb_build` in the README).

```
rake git="git://git.apache.org/couchdb.git tags/0.10.0" \
     install=/full/path/to/couch/dependencies           \
     couchdb_build=/full/path/to/couch/0.10.0

rake git="git://git.apache.org/couchdb.git tags/1.1.0"  \
     install=/full/path/to/couch/dependencies           \
     couchdb_build=/full/path/to/couch/1.1.0
```

With the `install` locations identical, Build CouchDB *should* skip the entire process to build and install dependencies when it builds 1.1.0. This includes:

- Erlang
- OTP
- Javascript

I believe this technique is used more often than the simpler one for side-by-side builds. Therefore it is possible this workaround will fix your error.

If you still have issues, it is probably a bug. Would you please submit a [Build CouchDB issue](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb/issues) indicating your operating system version and also attach your `rake.log` file?

Comment: Tried with no success, I have just filed an issue: https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb/issues/6

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get more recent versions of CouchDB installed side-by-side.

Comment: Awesome! More recent CouchDB versions have become more compatible, and that is becoming an explicit requirement in future versions.